# Unable to open debug or run my unpublished app on whitelisted devices

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I've tried to whitelist two chromecasts to test my unpublished app and can't open the debug menu or cast my app on either device. I've rebooted both several times and performed a factory reset on one hoping that would help, both devices are set to send their serial numbers when checking for updates. Could you suggest other possible solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own (published or unpublished) app should be running on Chromecast for debugger to be able to attach.

Comment: everything i read just said check http://<chromecast-ip>:9222 to verify the device is whitelisted, i didnt see anything about running your app on it first

Comment: This is a change made recently to enforce more security, see this post: https://plus.google.com/117916055521642810655/posts/THNdcXCwRUb

Comment: If you read our Debugging section under Custom receivers, in our developers documentations, we also state that clearly.

Comment: i hadn't read that section yet, i was just following the instructions at the bottom of this page https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to our attention, I will get that part updated too.